# Get input from bluetooth with Node js

Tags: bluetooth, pi-3b+, node.js

I want to use a raspberry pi 3B+ with node js to create a simple number counter that will be incremented by pressing a bluetooth button. I need a suggestion on the button to buy, and if it is possible to get the button press input with node js.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2016/02/cheap-bluetooth-buttons-and-linux/) can help you. I don't know Node.js, but I assume something similar can be done after you see the Python.

Comment: Too many hack to make it work, I've found a nice bluetooth smart button that fit all my needings.

Comment: How does that button communicate, Is there sample code?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad and opinion based. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. You wrote in a comment that you have found a usable button. So please edit your question and remove the part asking for a button. And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: please post a link to the button that you purchased